# Point to the sub folder Pom.xml from root pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I am working on spring boot application(with rest calls included) and i want to host it on heroku. Application works perfectly in my local machine.
Below is the Project Structure

.git

```
foldera

| 
  Mainclass
  Pom.xml

folderb

|
  other javacode
  pom.xml

folderc

|
  other javacode
  pom.xml

Pom.xml(within root folder)
```

pom.xml of root folder is shown below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
       </parent>
        <groupId>root</groupId>
    <artifactId>pomroot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Server Spring Boot</name>
    <description>Spring boot server for svmapp</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>./foldera</module>
       </modules>

</project>
```

I am using ./foldera to refer to subfolder using module tag. but this is not working.

All the folders are maven folders and added to the classpath. Now what i need is that from parent folder i want to refer to the Pom.xml of folder a.

How to achieve this?

Comment: You should not Access sub-modules from parent module.

Comment: @Jens I don't think that's what he meant. It seems to me that he wants to add submodules to the root POM, which is correct.

Comment: @coder12349 - You need to use the artifact ID instead of the module folder. i.e. if module inside `foldera` has artifactId `module_a`, your entry in the parent pom should be `<module>module_a</module>`

Comment: `<module>foldera</module>` should be enough. It will look for local folder with that name. The `./` in front is not required. It should not be an issue but just to be safe, try without it :)